# How to align(center) text inside childs of flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.cnt {
  display: flex;
}

.one {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 300px;
}

.two {
  background: #00ff00;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="one">
    Center me
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    And me
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there actually a way? Of course I may add another div inside and set it as I like, but I want it to be more elegant... so, is that actually possible to align this text horizontally, at least, without using another divs?

https://jsfiddle.net/cwfs3b0x/

Comment: `text-align:center` ???? Have you tried something ? https://jsfiddle.net/cwfs3b0x/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: thanks folks, I'm just an idiot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand you, this is just:

```
div {text-align: center}
```

Comment: No problem :) Sometimes things seem more complicated than they are haha, you can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah, I know :) In a minute it will allow me to accept